# Incorrect List manipulation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I want an output like

```
>>> b
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Here is my code:

```
class Child(object):
    def get_lines(self):
        a = [1,2,3,4,5]              
        b=[]
        c=[]
        j=0
        for i in a:
            print i
            b.append(i)
            print b
            c.insert(j,b)

            j=j+1
        print c


son= Child()
son.get_lines()
```

When I print list `b` in loop, it gives:

```
1 
[1] 
2 
[1, 2]
3  
[1, 2, 3]  
4  
[1, 2, 3, 4] 
5 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and the output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Where do I make wrong in the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` is **always the same list object** (note I've changed `print c` to `return c`):

```
>>> map(id, Child().get_lines())
...
[49021616, 49021616, 49021616, 49021616, 49021616]
```

`c` contains five references to the same list. I think what you want is:

```
class Child(object):

    def get_lines(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]              
        return [a[:x+1] for x in range(len(a))]
```

This makes a *shallow copy* of part (or all) of `a` for each step:

```
>>> Child().get_lines()
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
c.insert(j,b)
```

with:

```
 c.append(b[:])
```

and try again.

You need to make a copy of `b`. Otherwise you add the same `b` again and again resulting in the full list at all indices. 'b[:]' copies the list.

This solution does the same but is a bit shorter:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = []
for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
    c.append(a[:i])
```

now `c` is:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

`a[:i]` slices the list `a` from the beginning to excluding the index `i`.
In this case it does `a[:1]`, `a[:2]` and so on. `a[:1]` makes a new list [1], 
`a[:2]` a new list `[1, 2,]` and so on. Using `append()` is simpler and `insert()`.

Another alternative is a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[a[:i] for i in range(1, len(a) + 1)]
```

also results in:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: @JayVenkat I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, now i understood what you delivered :)

Answer (score 2):

Here in this case you are not supposed to append value to the list object (b).
since `list` is `mutable`, it will refer to the exact same object in memory until a reassign occurs.

```
>>> b=[]
>>> b.append(1)
>>> id(b)
4337935424
>>> b.append(2)
>>> id(b)
4337935424
>>> b.append(3)
>>> id(b)
4337935424
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(b)
4337942608
```

so that in your code `c` will make five references to the same list.

It will instruct a new object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

```
>>> class Child(object):
...
...     def get_lines(self):
...         a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
...         return map(lambda x: a[:x+1], range(len(a)))
...
>>> Child().get_lines()
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: hey your explanation made perfect on my doubts. Also, I've a doubt on **map**. Why do you use this structure and also lambda... In jonrsharpe's answer, he didn't use kind of that. Which is less time complexity?

Comment: Yes you are right Jay, It is nothing but I use lambda in simple iteration.

Comment: @JayVenkat in terms of time complexity `timeit` suggests that the list comprehension (mine) is fastest, then the copy (Mike/Serge) and `map` (Manikandan) is slowest, but this isn't by very much (2.04s, 2.43s and 2.85s respectively)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I was about to mention that. python -m timeit "a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; map(lambda x: a[:x+1], range(len(a)))" -->100000 loops, best of 3: 3.4 usec per loop.     python -m timeit "a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; [a[:x+1] for x in range(len(a))]"-->100000 loops, best of 3: 2.67 usec per loop

Answer (score 1):

You insert same `b` five times in list `c`. As a list actually contains references to objects and not copies, you have 5 times a reference to a same `b` list in which you have added successively 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So the result.

You must instead add **copies** of list b :

```
def get_lines(self):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]              
    b=[]
    c=[]
    j=0
    for i in a:
        print i
        b.append(i)
        print b
        c.insert(j,b[:]) # forces insertion of a copy

        j=j+1
    print c
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, value of `b` persists since it's a mutable object. Hence when you print `c`, the last value of `b` is shown.

Instead of using `b` as temporary variable, you can directly use `a` as follows:

```
class Child(object):
    def get_lines(self):
        a = [1,2,3,4,5]
        b = []
        for index, element in enumerate(a, 1):
            b.append(x[:index])
        return b


son= Child()
son.get_lines()
```